# Animating audio to waveform in a single direction

Tags: animation

I have looked through responses on here but haven't found a solution, so appreciate any help from someone more experienced :)

Referring to the attached image, I am trying to animate the shape so that it extrudes from the outer face of the cylinder but not inside towards the E. The outer face of the cylinder has been put into a vertex group and displace has been automated on it to follow f curve of an audio file. I have read about rigid bodies, but after having messed around I haven't been able to stop the shape from passing through to the inside.

I hope this explanation is sufficient and appreciate your help.

[image]

Kind regards

[image: edit - displace settings]

Comment: Please show displace modifier settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please see the photo in the edited post. Please note that I have tried altering the coordinates and the direction but with no success.